# Remove HTML code from JSON response

Tags: html, json, cakephp

I'm trying to get a response in JSON format, but CakePHP also includes in the response the html code of the page.
The function is this:

```
public function register() {
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $dataToSave = array(
                'User' => array(
                    'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                    'email' => $this->request->data['User']['email'],
                    'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password'],
                    'name' => $this->request->data['User']['name'],
                    'surname' => $this->request->data['User']['surname'],
                    'image_url' => "",
                ),
                'Filter' => array(
                    'Filter' => $this->request->data['Filter']['Filter']
                )
            );
            parent::uploadImageUser();
            $this->User->create();
            $dataToSave['User']['image_url'] = $this->image_path;

            $agent = $this->request->header('User-Agent');

            if ($this->User->saveAll($dataToSave)) {
                $this->set(compact("response", "success"));
                $this->set("_serialize", array("response"));
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                if ($agent != "FoodAdvisor client/Android"){                    
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'index')));
                }
            } 

            else {
                $this->set("response", "error");
                $this->set("_serialize", array("response"));
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }

        else {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('action'=>'index')));
            }
        }
    }
```

The response I get is this:
[image]

How can I remove the html code from my response?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by fixing whatever causes these notices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that 'User' index is defined on lines from 27 to 31 and that 'Filter' index is defined on line 35 of your file. Probably, `$this->request->data` does not contain User and Filter arrays.

Why not this way: `$dataToSave = $this->request->data;` ?

Answer (score 0):

after `if ($this->request->is('get'))` line, 
try to print the contents of `$this->request->data` i.e `pr($this->request->data)`. And check if you have 'User' index in the array. The error you got is probably due to missing the 'User' index in the array.